# Line break on input smaller than 100px, display flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, line-breaks

I'm doing a search box with tags, but there are no line-break when I add more than X tags.

The input with is 100% - "tag elements" ( width: -webkit-fill-available;) but I want to line break when the input with is minor than 100px for example, because now, the input field goes out of "inputholder" box.

Here you have an example code (If you press enter into input box, tag element is added to inputholder box):

This is my Html:

```js
$(".search-input").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $('#inputtext').before('<span class="tag">test-tag</span>');
    $('.search-input').val('');
  }
});
```

```css
.inputholder {
  /*border:1px solid black;*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #8D9BAF;
  width: 70%;
  /*padding:10px;*/
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.location-tag {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 20%;
}

.tag {
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #AAA;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*display: table-cell;*/
}

.tag-selected {
  background: #424242;
}

.inputholder input {
  border: 0 !important;
  padding: 12px !important;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background: transparent !important;
  color: #8D9BAF;
}

.inputholder input:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputholder">
  <span class="tag location-tag">
        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Ubicación
    </span>
  <input type="text" class="search-input" id="inputtext" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".search-input").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $('#inputtext').before('<span class="tag">test-tag</span>');
    $('.search-input').val('');
  }
});
```

```css
.inputholder {
  /*border:1px solid black;*/
  /*display: flex;*/
  align-items: baseline;
  padding-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #8D9BAF;
  width: 70%;
  /*padding:10px;*/
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.location-tag {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 20%;
}

.tag {
display:inline-flex;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #AAA;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*display: table-cell;*/
}

.tag-selected {
  background: #424242;
}

.inputholder input {
  border: 0 !important;
  padding: 12px !important;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background: transparent !important;
  color: #8D9BAF;
}

.inputholder input:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputholder">
  <span class="tag location-tag">
        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Ubicación
    </span>
  <input type="text" class="search-input" id="inputtext" />
</div>
```